# Make a checkbox tile clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a ReactJs application and I've made a modal with a form. My question looks like this:

[image: Form with images and radio buttons]

Over here all the images are connected to separate radio buttons and it makes the relevant selection when a user clicks on the radio button.
But I want the radio button to get triggered even when a user clicks on the image and not directly on the radio button, how can I do this?

My html:

```html
  
<div>
  <div className="category-card">
    <label htmlFor="square">
      <div className="card-icon">
        <img src="/img/icons/recommendation/square.svg"/>
      </div>
    </label>
    <div className="card-input">
      <input type="radio" name="categories" value="square" checked={this.state.filters.categories == "square"} onChange={this.handleFilterChange.bind(this)}  id="square"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *for*-attribute with each *label*-tag. So a label *for* a certain input-field *square* in other words.

Hope this helps you.

```html
  

<div>
    
    <label for="square">
      <img src="/img/icons/recommendation/square.svg"/>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="categories" value="square" id="square"/>
    
    <label for="square2">
      <img src="/img/icons/recommendation/square.svg"/>
    </label>
    <input type="radio" name="categories" value="square2" id="square2"/>
    
</div>
```

Comment: But I'm already using the for-attribute, with each label-tag. I don't think I can even remove my div around the image since I need it to style the svg

Comment: @anonn023432 I don't know anything about `React.js` but you're using `htmlFor`. The answer is suggesting you use the simple `for`.

Comment: Ofc you can, simply remove your `div` and make the label `display: block;` and assign the styles from the div to it.

Comment: @uom-pgregorio from what I understand `htmlFor` is exactly the same as `for`, it's just es6 syntax

Comment: for-attribute should also work even if a label tag is embedded into several div's as well as a certain input-field. but you have to define an id-attribute with a input-field.

Comment: @anonn023432 Just try it out. Simply replace `htmlFor` with `for`. No layout changes needed. And as @connexo says, you can make the `label` a block element and put the styling there.

Comment: @connexo thanks I was having trouble making it work this way, can't believe I didn't try `display: block`

Comment: I got it to work, after following your advice. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it works in React, but you should be able to move your closing `</label>` tag:

```
<div>
  <div className="category-card">
    <label htmlFor="square">
      <div className="card-icon">
        <img src="/img/icons/recommendation/square.svg"/>
      </div>
      <div className="card-input">
        <input type="radio" name="categories" value="square" checked={this.state.filters.categories == "square"} onChange={this.handleFilterChange.bind(this)}  id="square"/>
      </div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've also added what appears to be a missing `</div>` at the end.